# how do i make a GET request to Download a file using phphttpclient

Tags: httpful

Basically I would like to see an example on how to download a file.

I can't seem to find on phphttpclient website any doc or example about it.

In curl, the request would look like this:

curl -o hello.txt -H "X-Auth-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" http://site_where_to download/hello.txt

Thanks.

Comment: phphttpclient is a REST client for parsing JSON, XML and HTML, not downloading files. For that I would recommend other libraries.

Comment: Hi Kristian, Could you point me to a PHP library (that you have used and are satisfied with it) for making REST requests and also DOWNLOAD files?

Comment: You have [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) or [Requests](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests)

Comment: Request seems like a nice alternative. For downloading I just write the response->body into a file (not sure if this is the best way, but it works). I am not sure though how to make a file upload using PUT. Any pointer on how to do this (can't seem to find anything about this in the doc). Thanks.